# R Error 'Subscript out of bounds' in if statement - explanation and code fix?

Tags: r

I have a data frame (Dataset_Events) with seven columns, two of them being eventInfo_ea and eventInfo_el. I'd like to remove the cell value of eventInfo_el in rows where eventInfo_ea = 'add to cart'. See the code below.

```
 Remove = function(Dataset_Events, eventInfo_ea, eventInfo_el){
  if(Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]]=="add to cart"){
    Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_el"]] <- NULL
  }
 }
 sapply(Dataset_Events, Remove)
```

Unfortunately R gives me the following error message:
"Error in Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]] : subscript out of bounds"
Dimension of the dataframe are 713478 x 7.
Can anybody explain why and how to fix it?

If I simply run the if condition itself, I get a proper TRUE/FALSE reply in the same length as the data.frame

```
Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]]=="add to cart"
```

Here a sample dataset of the two relevant columns (both columns have class factor):

```
eventInfo_ea                                           eventInfo_el
1                click                                              thumbnail
2                click                                            description
3                click                                             hero image
4                click                                     open size dropdown
5                click                                             hero image
6                click                                             hero image
7                click                                             hero image
8                click                                            description
9                click                                     open size dropdown
10               click                                             hero image
11               click                                             hero image
12               click                                             hero image
13               click                                             hero image
14               click                                            description
15               click                                           open reviews
16               click                                             hero image
17               click                                           open reviews
18               click                                            description
19     add to wishlist                                             hero image
20               click                                             hero image
21               click                                             hero image
22         add to cart                                             hero image
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few things: `Remove()` has 3 arguments but you only use `Dataset_Events`.  You can simply your code inside the function as `Dataset_Events[ Dataset_Events["eventInfo_ea"]=="add to cart", ]["eventInfo_el"] <- NULL` and finally you want to pass a column from your `data.frame` to `sapply`. Finally it always helps to post a sample dataset, it makes it easier for people to test their solutions and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution that works. I skipped the whole part of defining a function and simply used the following code and it worked

```
Dataset_Events[ Dataset_Events["eventInfo_ea"]=="add to cart", ]["eventInfo_el"] <- NA
```

Still happy to hear though why the suggestions from all of you didn't seem to modify my dataset at all. Thanks a lot though!!!

Comment: sapply return the result. Doesn't modified the current argument. Every apply does that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Remove = function(Dataset_Events){
    ind = Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]] == "add to cart"
    Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_el"]][ind] = NA
    return (Dataset_Events)
    }
Remove(Dataset_Events)
```

I removed the second and third arguments from your function (you don't seem to be using them?). As you note, `Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]]=="add to cart"` gives you a vector of logicals, so this should be used to index the rows you want to set to `NA` (I changed from NULL since this was giving problems).

Comment: are you sure this is correct? Wouldn't `sapply`  apply `remove` to the columns of `Dataset_Event`? `Remove(Dataset_Events)` should work fine, right?

Comment: Yes, there isn't a need for `sapply` with this case. I had to just copied the line from OP

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to work. Even though I don't get an error message now, my dataframe looks exactly the same. The value of eventInfo_el where eventInfo_ea = "add to cart" is still the same as before and not NA

Comment: I added a `return` statement to the function. Is there still a problem? If so, what do you get with `sum(Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]] == "add to cart")`?

Comment: The return statement helped to get the correct dataset in the console but the actual dataset wasn't change. I found what was wrong though. I replaced 'Remove(Dataset_Events)' with 'Dataset_Events <- Remove(Dataset_Events)'. Now it worked

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the`Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_el"]]` returns a factor. In this case is better to use **identical**.

```
Remove = function(Dataset_Events, eventInfo_ea, eventInfo_el){
    if(identical(as.character(Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_ea"]]),"add to cart")){
        Dataset_Events[["eventInfo_el"]] <- NULL
    }
}
sapply(Dataset_Events, Remove)
```

Comment: I tried this with NA instead of NULL and with both sapply and simply Remove(Dataset_Events) as sapply gave me the same 'out of bounds' error. Now I don't get an error message, but simply nothing happens after Remove(Dataset_Events). The value of eventInfo_el did not change in the rows where eventInfo_ea == "add to cart".

Comment: can you please give us your dataset or and example to test it with the code? It is hard to tell without an example after mine and mickey's code doens't work...

Comment: I posted the dataset in my question above. Or is there another possibility to actually upload a file? Didn't see that anywhere